# Unrecognised ImageMagick Add Profile after upgrading to 11.2 from 7.4

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have a C# project using the ImageMagick library Magick.Net Q16 AnyCPU net40 targeting .Net 4.7.2 using VS 2022. After upgrading this from 7.4.6 to 11.2.1 using Nuget Package Manager the function image.AddProfile (where image is an ImageMagick image) is flagged as not present using the code below:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(sFileIn))
            {
                image.AddProfile(ExifProfile1);
```

The function image.AddNoise is present. I have a 'using ImageMagick' statement in the namespace. Looking at the ImageMagick namespace, AddProfile is defined as shown below:

```
 public unsafe void AddProfile(string? name, byte[] datum, int length)
```

How can I access the AddProfile function in this version of ImageMagick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer in the release notes: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/releases/tag/7.16.0.0. The `AddProfile` method has been renamed to `SetProfile`.